# Change this code to not construct the path from file name entry of an archive sonarcloud vulnerability

Tags: java, security, sonarqube

how i should in order to remove this security issue that sonarcloud finds?

Error on sonar

[image: 1]

I've already tried fixing with the advice sonar gives me but it doesn't work.

This is the code i tried to use

```
while ((entry = tarArchiveInputStream.getNextTarEntry()) != null) {
    if (entry.isDirectory()) {
        continue;
    }
    File curFile = new File(targetFile, entry.getName());
    File parent = curFile.getParentFile();
    String parentDirectory = parent.toString();
    if (!parent.exists() && !parentDirectory.startsWith("Dubbo/test")) {
        parent.mkdirs();
    }
    try (FileOutputStream outputStream = new FileOutputStream(curFile)) {
        IOUtils.copy(tarArchiveInputStream, outputStream);
    }
```

It gives error on line 73

Thank you in advance